# Select 1 record for ever 5 records using LINQ

Tags: sql, linq

Is there a way to select one record per 5 records in SQL Server with LINQ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do server side directly with LINQ to SQL. There is a client side solution, however:

```
 var result = new DataContext().Table.AsEnumerable()
                     .Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Item = x })
                     .Where(t => t.Index % 5 == 0).Select(t => t.Item);
```